# sympy - UnevaluatedExpr and commutative property - keep a float number unevaluated

Tags: sympy

I have the following expression: `Bg = (pi / H)**2 + (2.405 / R)**2`. In my computations I would like to keep the float number `2.405` unevaluated, otherwise I end up with long floats numbers scattered all around my expressions.

I thought I could use sympy `UnevaluatedExpr` to represent that float number. That worked nicely to further develop my expressions. The problem is that expressions containing `UnevaluatedExpr` are non-commutative, thus I cannot use methods like `solve()`, `factor()`, `collect()`, ... otherwise they throw errors complaining about the non-commutative nature of the expression.

The following code shows that the expression is non-commutative because I used `UnevaluatedExpr`.

```
import sympy as sp
R, H = sp.symbols("R, H", real=True, positive=True)

Bg = (sp.pi / H)**2 + (sp.UnevaluatedExpr(2.405) / R)**2
print(Bg)
print(Bg.is_commutative)

>>> 2.405**2/R**2 + pi**2/H**2
>>> False
```

whereas the following code shows that the expression is commutative, though the float number was evaluated:

```
Bg = (sp.pi / H)**2 + (2.405 / R)**2
print(Bg)
print(Bg.is_commutative)

>>> 5.784025/R**2 + pi**2/H**2
>>> True
```

Questions:

1. Can the `UnevaluatedExpr` and commutative behaviour be a bug?
2. What's the best way to deal with float number and prevent their evaluation? I thought about substituting the number with a symbol: that's fine for my simple example but if I work on bigger expressions it could quickly turn to a mess.

Comment: How does it become messy to replace multidigit numbers that you want to track with a single symbol?

Comment: A single symbol is fine, no mess. But when I have dozen or more floats to substitute with a different symbol, situation change dramatically. The `UnevaluatedExpr` approach was appealing because whenever an expression showed a float, I could call a custom method that would substitute the float digit with the `UnevaluatedExpr(digit)`.

Comment: If you spell `UnevaluatedExpr = lambda x: Symbol(str(x))` that would replace the float with a string whose name is the float value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would consider this to be a bug. I would suggest opening an issue about it https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new.

You can use a Symbol. Another idea would be to use a class that explicitly wraps a float, like

```py
class UnevaluatedFloat(Expr):
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        return Expr.__new__(cls, Float(arg))

    def _eval_evalf(self, prec):
        return self.args[0]._eval_evalf(prec)

    def _sympystr(self, printer):
        return printer.doprint(self.args[0])
```

This will create a class that gives the float when you call `evalf` but stays unevaluated otherwise. It also prints as the float. I added the str printer, but you can also define the other printing methods you care about in the same way, like `_pretty` and `_latex` and so on. Search for "printmethod" at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html.

Example

```
>>> UnevaluatedFloat(1.0) + 1
1 + 1.0
>>> (UnevaluatedFloat(1.0) + 1).evalf()
2.00000000000000
```